# How to render placeholders from a django-cms custom templatetag?

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-templates

I've made a simple template tag to list child pages in a django-cms site.
It's working fine except for the fact that I have not been able to render the child pages placeholders in the template tag itself.

The following is my code for the template tag.

**subpages.py**

```
from cms.models import Page
from cms.utils.page_resolver import get_page_from_path

from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('subpages.html', takes_context = True)
def get_news_items( context ):
    request = context['request']
    subpages = request.current_page.children.filter(published=True)
    return {'subpages':subpages}
```

**subpages.html**

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags placeholder_tags %}
<ul>
{% for item in subpages %}
    <li><a href="/{{ item.get_path }}">{{ item.get_title }}</a>
        {% render_placeholder subtitle %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I've tried some alternatives to *render_placeholder* but without luck.

How would be the correct way to get the placeholder rendered?

Comment: {% render_placeholder [placeholder] %} expects to receive a placeholder instance. I'm guessing `subtitle` is not the correct type.

Comment: subtitle is how my placeholder is named in the child page, what do you mean by correct type?

In my template for the page I have: {% placeholder subtitle %} and it works.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can't render a placeholder by name, you have to hand `{% render_placeholder %}` a placeholder instance, like a placeholder field on a model. See: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/extending_cms/placeholders.html#templates

Comment: I see, if I do **item.placeholders.all** in the for statement in the template, I do get the placeholders name, so, what would be the correct parameter to pass to render_placeholder? something like item.placeholder.subtitle didn't work.

Comment: I would try: `item.placeholder` since that is a reference to the object.

Comment: It doesn't work either, I'm thinking because the item has many placeholders (subtitle, content, and image). So how would it know which placeholder to render?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try looping over the placeholder instances, passing in each placeholder to the render method.

Comment: I tried looping through the placeholders without success, I can get each instance but the render_placeholder renders nothing. You can check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anabelle/0a7f5a64468b6d4903cc) where I put the template and the corresponding output, you can see the loop shows each instance but render_template does nothing.

Comment: Hmm. That seems logical. Probably time to ping the Django-CMS Google Group, or log an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a (untested) suggestion, but try passing the context along to the template:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('subpages.html', takes_context = True)
def get_news_items( context ):
    request = context['request']
    subpages = request.current_page.children.filter(published=True)
    context.update({'subpages':subpages})
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tested it and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there a way to place a templatetag tag like this one: {% placeholder "subtitle" %} in a custom templatetag template and render and safe plugins correctly?